what kind of soil do I purchase for growing a redwood tree
What type of soil can I purchase for a redwood tree that I'm growing?

Are you growing this indoors or outside.  If outside, where in the world?  Can you add a picture?

Trees, especially tall ones like the Redwood have very deep roots.  Any soil on tbe top is not going to be of much use when its grown up.
That means you just need normal, friable soil with mulch around the root ball, when you plant it. Not too clayey, not too sandy, not too rich.
